# Ant string manipulation

Tags: ant

Is there any additional ant tasks(or external plugins) to convert string to lower case and trim. i got some idea by surfing, but all represents via script that has to be done. I need the manipulation should be done using ant script alone(without using java script).

Comment: What's wrong with javascript? It comes bundled with the JVM. Far simpler compared to writing an ANT task.

Comment: Yeah i tried with javascript, its working fine. but need to know that is there any other ways to do string manipulation in ant itself? is there any external addon/ plugins available...?